# How to hide panel

Tags: modeling

I dnt want this gap between the screencast and gizmo. How to hide or make it go away. No way I can unflap it. I want the gizmo attached/below to the options.

Thank you.

[image]

Comment: what does it give if you press N?

Comment: Awwwwwww. it goes away.!! come again another day! hahaha. Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just press <kbd>N</kbd> and wait until the panel retracts on the right

[image]

Comment: I cant accept answer in 3 minutes? I have to wait for 3 minutes? weird

Comment: I know where N is in keyboard. :@

Comment: I try to be as helpful as possible

Comment: hahahahahahhahah

Comment: also as you are blue maybe your finger is not orange

Comment: lol. you drew a finger to point N! I cant stop laughing!

Comment: +1 for the step by step illustration :DD